# Scheme language case conditional with multiple tests?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

What I'm trying to do is shown below in pseudo code:

```
case (test0, test1)
  begin
    (false,false): statement 0;
    (false,true): statement 1;
    (true,false): statement 2;
    (true,true): statement 3;
  end
```

How to do it in scheme using the case conditional? The problem is that case uses the `eqv?` predicate which it seems will always return false (because `(eqv? '(#f . #f) '(#f . #f))` evaluates to `#f`). Would appreciate any reasonably concise way of expressing above pattern in scheme (other than the obvious breaking it down into nested if conditionals).

**Edit:** Valid answers below lead me to reframe my query slightly: how would a seasoned schemer code up the above pattern?

Comment: Looks like you want some pattern matching in Scheme. I believe you can find macro packages doint that.

Comment: Basile, I can express the stated pattern in Haskell in a manner almost similar to the pseudocode shown. Since it seems to be reasonably common pattern, hoping it can be done in scheme simply without resorting to macros...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good fit for Racket's [`match`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html):

```
(define (test pair)
  (match pair
    ['(#f . #f) "statement 1"]
    ['(#f . #t) "statement 2"]
    ['(#t . #f) "statement 3"]
    ['(#t . #t) "statement 4"]
    [else (error "unknown expression:" pair)]))
```

For example:

```
(test '(#t . #f))
=> "statement 3"

(test (cons (= 0 0) (= 1 1)))
=> "statement 4"

(test '(a . b))
=>  unknown expression: (a . b)
```

Comment: Seems a reasonably good approach as similar match implementations are typically found in other scheme implementations as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way, illustrating an approach:

```
(case (+ (if test0 10 0) (if test1 1 0))
  ((11) …)
  ((10) …)
  ((01) …)
  ((00) …))
```

How would I actually do it… If there is any asymmetry in the importance between `test0` and `test1` I would simply use `if` with the most important `test` first.  As such, assuming `test0` is more important:

```
(if test0
    (if test1
        …  ;; (and test0 test1)
        …) ;; (and test0 (not test1))
    (if test1
        …   ;; …
        …)) ;; …
```

If there is no difference whatsoever in importance, then:

```
(cond ((and test0 test1) …)
      ((and test0 (not test1)) …)
      …)
```

If it is a common pattern with two variables, then I'd define a macro that allows me to specify the four bodies within a lexical binding of test0 and test1:

```
(define-syntax if-two-way
  (syntax-rules (tt tf ft ff)
    ((if-two-way test0 test1
       (tt btt1 btt …)
       (tf btf1 btf …)
       (ft bft1 bft …)
       (ff bgg1 bff …))
     (let ((t0 test0) (t1 test1))
       (if t0
           (if t1
               (begin btt1 btt …)
               (begin btf1 btf …))
           …))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use `cond` and `equal?`:

```
(define (test pair)
  (cond
    ((equal? pair '(#f . #f)) "statement 0")
    ((equal? pair '(#f . #t)) "statement 1")
    ((equal? pair '(#t . #f)) "statement 2")    
    ((equal? pair '(#t . #t)) "statement 3")
    (else                     "wot?")))
```